# Javascript return with string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function that returns selected

```
function getage() {
    var selectedAge = selectedYear;
    var selectedAge = "";
    console.log(selectedAge);
    for (var key in selectedAge) { // run for every value in selectedAge
        console.log(key);
        if (selectedBirth.indexOf('20-' + key) > -1){
            if (selectedAge[key].length > 0) { // check if the subarray of selectedAge contains a value (if birth has selected age)
                selectedAge = selectedAge + age[key] + " selectedAge"; // add the age code as well as 'selected age' to return string
            } else {
                selectedAge = selectedAge + birth[key]; // adds only birth name
            }    
            selectedAge = selectedAge + "\n" + "\t";
        }
    }
    return selectedAge;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: where do you want to display it? html? plain text? console?

Comment: Do not vandalize your question. Make or accept an answer if it's "fixed".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new line...

- in your HTML **code** (or strings in general), use `\n`
- in your HTML **output**, use the `<br/>` tag
- in both your HTML **code** and its **output**, combine them (like `<br/>\n`)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

try to add this `var breakline = document.createElement("br");` in the code and add it to your `selectedString`

```
function getCoverage() {
  var selectedMarkers = selectedTowns;
  var selectedString = "";
  var breakline = document.createElement('br');
  selectedString.appendChild(breakline);
  console.log(selectedMarkers);
  for (var key in selectedMarkers) { // run for every value in selectedMarkers
    console.log(key);
    if (selectedRegions.indexOf('ZA-' + key) > -1) { // if current province is one of the selected provinces
      if (selectedMarkers[key].length > 0) { // check if the subarray of selectedMarkers contains a value (if province has selected town)
        selectedString = selectedString + province[key] + " selected towns"; // add the province code as well as 'selected towns' to return string
      } else {
        selectedString = selectedString + province[key]; // adds only province name (since regional coverage for this province)
      }    
      selectedString = selectedString
    }
  }

  return selectedString;
}
```

Comment: please use `<br/>` instead of `</br>`

Comment: I've tried adding "<br/>". Doesn't work as well. Just prints out "<br/>" with string.

Comment: @Gijsberts Hi thanks but still not working only prints out "[object HTMLBRElement]" where the line break is suppose to be.

Comment: BTW `<br/>` is exactly the same as `<br>` in HTML5. According to the spec, `/` is ignored and the tag is simply treated as `<br>`.

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn : In XHTML, the `/` in `<br/>` is mandatory. So, leaving it there both improves readability (as it's more obvious that the tag is self-closing) and improves backward compatibility with pre-HTML5 environments.

Comment: XHTML is obsolete since December 2010. It's been almost six years already. Let it go. Moreover it's bad idea to use `/>` because it can lead to further confusion due to the significant difference between `<foo/>` in XHTML and HTML5. The former is indeed a self-closing tag (`<foo></foo>`), while in HTML5 it's treated as opening tag (`<foo>`).

Comment: hmmm ... the answer to your question depends on Where the string returned will be used. WHEN it is in a `<textarea>...</textarea>` as the `value` then you ought to be able to use the `"\n"` because it is just loose text.  In instead it is part of the document page, e.g. inside a block like `<div> ...string here... </div>`; you will need to update the innerHTML of your element.  Finally, since you describe a *list of things* why not emit a `<ul><li> str1 </li> <li> str2 </li> ... </ul>` and give-up the line breaking -- Leave that to the browser, that is what its job is, to format strings.

Answer (score 0):

In `html`, either just use `<br />` where you would have wanted to use `\n`, or wrap every item in a `display: block` element like `div` or `p` or `li`.

You then have to make sure that your html is not escaped before inserting into the page, by using a function like jQuery's `.html()` or `element.innerHTML = "...";`.

Answer (score 0):

Another try, try to add the string in a element like a `p` or a `h1` or something

```
function getCoverage() {
    var selectedMarkers = selectedTowns;
    var selectedString = "";
    console.log(selectedMarkers);
    for (var key in selectedMarkers) { // run for every value in selectedMarkers
        console.log(key);
        if (selectedRegions.indexOf('ZA-' + key) > -1) { // if current province is one of the selected provinces
            if (selectedMarkers[key].length > 0) { // check if the subarray of selectedMarkers contains a value (if province has selected town)
                selectedString = selectedString + province[key] + " selected towns"; // add the province code as well as 'selected towns' to return string
            } else {
                selectedString = selectedString + province[key]; // adds only province name (since regional coverage for this province)
            }    
            selectedString = selectedString;
        }
    }
    return "<p>" + selectedString + "</p>";
}
```